# Center text with printf

Tags: bash, text-formatting, printf

```
printf "%*s\n" $(((${#fname}+$COLUMNS)/2)) "$fname"
```

I get this error:

```
line 9: (7+)/2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ")/2")
```

This works in the terminal but not in my script. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: [LINES and COLUMNS environmental variables lost in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016366/4023950)

Comment: Thanks for the info...

Comment: I used  ```shopt -s checkwinsize; (:;:)```

Answer (score 5):

Not all shells set the `$COLUMNS` variable to the width of the terminal.

`bash` versions prior to 5.0 only set it when interactive, not in scripts. However, since version 4.3, you can still enable it in non-interactive shells with `shopt -s checkwinsize`.

In either case, there is however a twist: with that option enabled in non-interactive shells (enabled by default since 5.0), `$COLUMNS`/`$LINES` are not set until a child process has been waited for and exited (the `NEWS` entry in the source mentions *after a foreground job exits*, which is a bit misleading given that there's no job control by default in non-interactive shells). So you need to make sure an external command or subshell has been run synchronously before using those variables:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s checkwinsize # for versions 4.3 and 4.4
(:) # start a synchronous subshell that runs the null command
echo "$COLUMNS $LINE"
```

Also note that it only happens if stderr goes to the terminal (and if not, `$COLUMNS` remains unset), so you may want to use something like `${COLUMNS:-80}` to use a saner default when `bash` can't determine the screen width.

Alternatively, you could switch to `zsh` which always sets `$COLUMNS` even when non-interactive as long as it's running in a terminal (and `$COLUMNS` defaults to 80 otherwise) or, in any Bourne-like shell use `${COLUMNS:=$(tput cols)}` in place of `$COLUMNS` for `$COLUMNS` to be set from the output of `tput cols` if it was previously unset or empty.

If `tput cols` doesn't work on your system, you can try `</dev/tty stty size | awk '{print $2}'`, or `zsh -c 'print $COLUMNS'`

Beware however that once `$COLUMNS` has been set in that way, it won't get updated whenever the terminal is resized¹, so you may want to use `$(tput cols)` always instead so the terminal size is queried every time you print centred text in your script.

Also beware that [`printf '%*s'` in shells other than `zsh` and `fish` pads text to the given number of *bytes* not *characters*](/q/350240), so that approach can only be used to pad text containing single byte, single width characters which in locales using UTF-8 is limited to the US-ASCII ones (0.011% of all possible characters).

If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could use its `l`eft and `r`ight padding parameter expansion flags instead (which can even handle zero-width or double-width characters with the `m` flag):

```
print -r -- ${(ml[COLUMNS/2]r[COLUMNS-COLUMNS/2])fname}
```

Note that it pads both to the left and the right (so to the right edge of the screen). You can remove the right padding (along with all trailing whitespace) with:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -r -- ${${(ml[COLUMNS/2]r[COLUMNS-COLUMNS/2])fname}%%[[:space:]]#}
```

Centring text that contains colouring / bold / standout... escape sequences would be more complicated. Easiest would probably be to remove them before getting the width of the string. For instance, with `zsh`, using [that approach](/a/591447) to determine string width (and handling 0-width or double-width characters).

```
varwidth() (( ${(P)#1} * 3 - ${#${(ml[${(P)#1} * 2])${(P)1}}} ))
functions -Ms varwidth

varwidth_without_formatting() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  local without_formatting=${(P)1//$'\e'\[[0-9;]#m}
  (( varwidth(without_formatting) ))
}
functions -Ms varwidth_without_formatting

center() {
  local text
  for text do
    print -r -- ${(l[(COLUMNS-varwidth_without_formatting(text))/2])}$text
  done
}

center $'\e[31mred\e[1;39mbold\e[m' \
       ${(%):-%F{green}Blah%F{yellow}blah%F{magenta}blah%f}
```

---

<sup>¹ though on most systems you could install a handler for the SIGWINCH signal as @zevzek showed in comments which would help in the most common cases.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the info. I really helps

Comment: I used:shopt -s checkwinsize; (:;:)

Comment: Thanks @Dark_Stoner, I wasn't aware of that. I see it's even enabled by default since 5.0 but with that bizarre limitation. I've included it in the answer.

Comment: @zevzek, yes, though I didn't want to get into that as you need to mention the many limitations (for instance wrt subshells, functions, etc) with that with different shells.

Comment: Oh about strings that use escape patererns?

Comment: How about centering strings that use escape patterns?  "\e[1;30;48;5;220m  foo e[0m"

Comment: @Dark_Stoner, see edit.

Comment: Geeeze I think I'll just use kitty ikat and center the image. Thnx. I didn't know it would be that difficult. Thnx, didn't think it would be so convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the variable COLUMNS you can try to get the value from external source:

```
tput cols 

stty size | cut '-d ' -f1
```

Comment: Thanx, It helps my understanding a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
read WindowHeight WindowWidth<<<$(stty size)
printf "%$(((${#fname}+${WindowWidth})/2))s" "$fname"
```

COLUMNS is not set automatically in script, so good chois is to use stty to get current window size. this will work in multiple shells (including bash, ksh, zsh)

Comment: Neither `<<<` nor `stty size` are POSIX though (`<<<` comes from zsh, [`stty size` will be in the next POSIX version though](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1053)). Note that `read` splits words according to the current value of `$IFS`, so the above assumes `$IFS` still contains space or whatever character `stty` uses in your locale to separate the numbers (POSIX will require it being one classified as blank), and no digit.

Comment: I am not sure that ```<<<``` comes from zsh, it available in bash and it is just a short version of document here construction
"https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html"
Maybe I should replace "posix" with non-bash construction, as it is available not only in bash and do the things in script and out of them.