# Shell function to center its first argument

Tags: function, printf, whitespace

In the nano text editor, I can pipe the selection into a command, and I quite often need to center text, so I came up with the following code

```
center() {
  str=$1
  # Strip leading and trailing whitespace from the string
  str=$(echo "$str" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
  str_len=${#str}
  margin=$(((80 - str_len) / 2))
  printf "%*s%s%*s\n" $margin "" "$str" $margin ""
}
```

But I don't know much about scripting so I'd like to know how I could improve this code.

Why are you linking to a bash solution? I don't use this shell, I just want it to run with sh

Comment: If switching to `vim` is an option, it's just `:center` there (based on the `textwidth` aka `tw` setting).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center text with printf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674625/center-text-with-printf)

Comment: Regarding your most recent edit: `bash` answers were suggested as this is the most common shell in use, and you did not specify a particular shell in the question. Note also that my own answer did already have a `sh`-only part to it, which I hope I have now pointed out a bit more explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `bash` shell (see the end of this answer if not using `bash`), you can strip flanking whitespace from the string in `str` more efficiently using standard variable expansions and the extended globbing pattern `+([[:space:]])` (matches one or more space-like characters):

```bash
shopt -s extglob

str=$1
str=${str##+([[:space:]])}  # strip at start
str=${str%%+([[:space:]])}  # strip at end
```

We would want to print the string right-justified to the column given by (*w*+*s*)/2, where *w* is the width of the terminal (outputted by `tput cols`, but you may also use `$COLUMNS`) and *s* is the length of the string (`${#str}`):

```bash
printf '%*s\n' "$(( ( $(tput cols) + ${#str} ) / 2 ))" "$str"
```

The function:

```bash
center () (
    shopt -s extglob

    str=$1
    str=${str##+([[:space:]])}
    str=${str%%+([[:space:]])}

    printf '%*s\n' "$(( ( $(tput cols) + ${#str} ) / 2 ))" "$str"
)
```

Note that the body of the function is a sub-shell.  This is so that the setting of the `extglob` shell option does not spill over into the calling shell.

Without relying on `extglob` (will work in any `sh`):

```bash
center () {
    str=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
    printf '%*s\n' "$(( ( $(tput cols) + ${#str} ) / 2 ))" "$str"
}
```

Replace `$(tput cols)` with `80` if you want to format this to a static 80-column width.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: Note that in bash and POSIX compliant sh/printf. `${#var}` gives you the length in number of *characters* while `printf '%*s'` pads to a number of *bytes*, so it can only be used for  single-byte single-width characters.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have multiple whitespaces concatenated in the middle, you may simplify the trimming with `str=$(echo $1)`

```
center () {
  str=$(echo $1)
  len=${#str}
  margin=$((($COLUMNS - len) / 2))
  printf "%${margin}s%s\n" " " "$str"
}
```

You don't need to append whitespace after `$str`.

Comment: the unquoted expansion of `$1` would also process any glob patterns, so if your text is e.g. `2 * 3 + 5`, or `** NOTE: blahblah **`, you get some weird results. (well, just a list of filenames)

Comment: Note that some shells don't initialise a `COLUMNS` variable.